# How to extract a DataFrame to obtain a nested array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample DataFrame as below:
First column consists of 2 years, for each year, 2 track exist and each track includes pairs of longitude and latitude coordinated. How can I extract every track for each year separately to obtain an array of tracks with lat and long?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'year':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
    'track_number':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], 
    'lat': [11.7,11.8,11.9,11.9,12.0,12.1,12.2,12.2,12.3,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.6,12.7,12.8], 
    'long':[-83.68,-83.69,-83.70,-83.71,-83.71,-83.73,-83.74,-83.75,-83.76,-83.77,-83.78,-83.79,-83.80,-83.81,-83.82,-83.83]})
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` year and then extract a `numpy.array` from the created dataframes with `.to_numpy()`.

```
>>> years = []
>>> for _, df2 in df.groupby(["year"]):
        years.append(df2.to_numpy()[:, 1:]) 
>>> years[0]
    array([[  0.  ,  11.7 , -83.68],
           [  0.  ,  11.8 , -83.69],
           [  0.  ,  11.9 , -83.7 ],
           [  0.  ,  11.9 , -83.71],
           [  1.  ,  12.  , -83.71],
           [  1.  ,  12.1 , -83.73],
           [  1.  ,  12.2 , -83.74],
           [  1.  ,  12.2 , -83.75]])
>>> years[1] 
    array([[  0.  ,  12.3 , -83.76],
           [  0.  ,  12.3 , -83.77],
           [  0.  ,  12.4 , -83.78],
           [  0.  ,  12.5 , -83.79],
           [  1.  ,  12.6 , -83.8 ],
           [  1.  ,  12.6 , -83.81],
           [  1.  ,  12.7 , -83.82],
           [  1.  ,  12.8 , -83.83]])
```

Where `years[0]` would have the desired information for the year `0`. And so on. Inside the array, the positions of the original `dataframe` are preserved. That is, the first element is the track; the second, the latitude, and the third, the longitude.

If you wish to do the same for the track, i.e, have an array of only latitude and longitude, you can `groupby(["year", "track_number"])` as well.